# Installing PyTorch in Google Colabs

Tags: pip, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am currently trying to run my code in Google Colabs and for that I need PyTorch. This is the feedback I got.

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-3d0da87b83cc> in <module>()
     13 #from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
     14 get_ipython().system('pip install torch')
---> 15 import torch
     16 get_ipython().system('pip install transformers')
     17 from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py in <module>()
>     195     if USE_GLOBAL_DEPS:
>     196         _load_global_deps()
> --> 197     from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
>     198 
>     199 # Appease the type checker; ordinarily this binding is inserted by the
> 
> ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC
```

I read that it could have to do with Numpy and tried another version, which also failed.

Comment: This works. Question answered:

Comment: I've removed my comment and posted it below as an answer. If you don't mind, please accept the answer so that others can see that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old numpy and run the following code.

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Found the solution [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/valueerror-and-importerror-occurred-when-import-torch/5818/2).